# Why is there no panning animation when setting userTrackingMode to Follow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary, geolocation

I have an MKMapView here in my app:

[image]

When I pan the map view to set the tracking mode to None (and the button on the lower right corner will empty its brown fill, only showing its stroke), and click that button again to change the tracking mode to Follow, the map view doesn't animate and pan continuously to the current location, instead it jumps to that location in a sudden.

Why is this? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that it was just a typo. Really remember to use "setUserTrackingMode" with animated true instead of just setting the userTrackingMode property! I was using Swift, so it can be really easily missed.